# Client Server API interaction

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, server, client

I am writing a client server program and it is my idea to have the server as simple as possible.  The server will need to complete tasks such as "move this file", "delete a file" , run this complex algorithm on the columns in a file and send back results.

I have created an abstract class that will be sent between server and client called aTodo
There is one method called DoClass() in this abstract class that is to be run by the server.

Currently my server listens and waits for a connection.  When it receives a connection it creates an object of type aTodo via unserialization.  Then the server runs the DoClass function in that object.  The server then serializes the object and sends it back to the client.
here is the code for reference:

```
protocolBaseServer pBase(newSockFd); //create socket
std::unique_ptr<aTodo> DoThis; //create object variable
DoThis=protocolCom::Read<aTodo>(pBase); //read the stream into the variable

DoThis->DoClass();//call the do function in the 
protocolCom::Write(DoThis,pBase);//write back to the client
```

Is this a good way to program a server? It is VERY simple on the server.

Another way I was thinking was to create a delegate class that would be serialized and sent back and forth. The delegate would have a DoDelegate method. Then the user could put ANY function into the delegate's DoDelegate method.  This would in affect allow the server to run any method in a class rather than just the Single DoClass method I have the server run now.

Thanks

Comment: In the absense of a SSCCE we can't provide concrete feedback. Perhaps you aren't looking for that though, which is why I provided my answer nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a way good to dream...

How would you be serializing the generic delegate? That's not something that C++ facilitates...

Also, at this point your client must contain all the logic that the server implements. Because you're actually sending server classes via serialization.

I think you need to separate the command objects and the handlers that implement the corresponding actions.

Also, I would suggest that the server queues the commands received and a separate worker processes the commands from the queue.

The common way to approach this is using a framework for asynchronous socket io, such as ACE or Asio.

Comment: Like "DeleteFileCommand" and "DeleteFileCommandHandler"? I mean, I would do without the inheritance hierarchy, but if that floats your boat...

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the idea conceptually. I mean, we have thin clients, why not have thin servers? Of course, C++ is not usable for this at all - as any solution would require to send over actual CODE for execution. Butr on a language which support this, this might me a nead design.

Comment: Yeah. Well, we're not discussing dreamland (besides, that dreamland would be steeped in security vulnerabilities and problems of configuration management). In the case at hand the obvious problem is the cost of maintenance where any fix to to client or server code necessitates a recompile, redeploy and restart of all clients as well.

Comment: so in general when coding server client apps.  How do you tell the server to "go list the directories in /home/foo" and send me back the list? A lot of examples online are simple echo servers.  How would I accomplish what I want to do?

Comment: I believe it may be smarter for me to develope an interface class.  The server can then read this interface class and then determine what the client wants it to do?

Comment: rather than come up with my own idea of how servers and clients should talk I am going to learn RPC.  Thanks. I was just wondering if  I was way off base, which I am.

Comment: I'd personally make a command grammar. I'd make it text based (JSON perhaps). Going full RPC is seems a little bit like overkill, although if you use an existing implementation (CORBA, COM, ...) and the application is large, I would not say it's untypical